# Wrong icon for Widget Extension scheme after rename

Tags: xcode, rename, widgetkit, xcode15, ios17

I had renamed my Widget Extension struct from "PropediumWidgetExtension" to "Widget" and updated corresponding values in the extension's Building Settings. The icon for the Widget Extension as target in the right sidebar is right, but the one for the run scheme is wrong...

[image: Target membership icon]
[image: Run scheme icon]

I tried creating a new scheme for the widget extension but the icon is still wrong.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!